# Partial Spearman's Correlation in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm using this data set: https://github.com/jenineharris/statistics-in-R-data-sets/blob/master/water_educ_2015_who_unesco_ch8.csv

and the question asks me to

1. Create a new variable by re-coding the perc.1dollar variable into 10 categories: 0 to < 10, 10 to < 20, 20 to < 30, and so on.
   The new variable should have a logical name and clear labels.

[Screenshot of recoding variable into 10 categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOuVX.png)

2. Conduct the partial correlation between females in school and basic water access accounting for poverty by including this new variable. Use the appropriate kind of partial correlation (Pearson's or Spearman's) given the variable type for the new variable.

[Screenshot of partial Spearman's correlation with new variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0HGy.png). I ran a Spearman's correlation because the variable is ordinal.

I've included screenshots for what I've done so far but I keep getting this error: Error in pcor(water.cleaned, method = "spearman") : 'x' must be numeric.

I was told that the labels for the breaks that are numeric and ordinal and it should fix the error but I'm still not able to fix the error.